# Cannot Extend and Implement at the Same Time

Tags: php, oop

I get an error when I try to instantiate the following:

```
$main = new Main();
$main->run();    

class Main
{
  public function run() {
    $instance = new C();  
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'C' not found in /path/to/file/test.php on line xx
```

Everything needs to be in the same file, so I have the following setup for classes and interfaces:

```
interface A { ... }
abstract class B { ... }
class C extends B implements A { ... }
```

This order makes sense and I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. Also, the Main class is defined before interface A.

Comment: The code itself is correct, the problem lies in the include/require(whatever you're using). By that error I'm assuming you're also using namespaces. If you are, make sure you're using them properly.

Comment: I'm not including/requiring any files. Everything is located in one file in the order I specified. I'm also not using namespaces.

Comment: Okay then. Could you put the actual code for the classes here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code order is incorrect. like most interpreters and compilers, php is a top to bottom language, meaning that everything that is used, must be defined before the usage.

The correct order for the code is as follows:

```
/*1*/ interface A { ... }
/*2*/ abstract class B { ... }
/*3*/ class C extends B implements A { ... }
/*4*/ class Main
      {
          public function run()
          {
              $instance = new C();  
          }
      }
/*5*/ $main = new Main();
/*6*/ $main->run();
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! Tried it by moving Main under all the definitions, but forgot to move the calls related to Main.

Comment: `meaning that everything that is used, must be defined before the usage.` what??? not at all. You can declare a function after using it in a script. just try `echo hello(); function hello(){return 'hello';}`. the function is defined after it is used

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier It is the matter of scope. In the same scope, definitions are "Like" concurrent; it doesn't matter where to define a class or method. But as the scope changes, It is important that the class to be instantiated or the method called is already defined. In this example, when class `C` is instantiated in class `Main` scope, it is important that `C` is defined already in outer scope.

Comment: yes, important that it be defined in outer scope, and that can be *after* `run()` is called... or anywhere in this outer scope